# 'babelHelpers.asyncToGenerator is not a function' error

Tags: javascript, babeljs, react-native, react-native-ios

#### Expected Behavior

App to load as it does on android.

#### Actual Behavior

Error: `babelHelpers.asyncToGenerator is not a function`

[image: iOS Simulator (10.3 @ iPhone 6)]

## Environment:

```
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.1
Node: 7.9.0
Yarn: 0.20.3
npm: 4.2.0
Watchman: 4.9.0
Xcode: Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
Android Studio: 2.3 AI-162.4069837
```

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: @Rob Considering I can't copy and paste all of error due to being in simulator, this was the only option. Screenshoting React Native error boxes is pretty common method so try and be helpful or ignore the question.

Comment: If you are able to screen it, you are able to type it in. It is a requirement as I linked to. You risk your question being closed altogether. In addition, you have supplied none of the required code to help debug this for you. [mcve]

Comment: Watch your language!

Comment: As for example code, I'm not sure exactly what is causing error and the project is big so excuse my breaking of your rules while I figure this out.

Comment: And that is why your question will be closed. We can't help someone blindly.

Comment: Thanks. You've been helpful :+1:

Answer (score 1):

Check your `.babelrc` file. Is it including the babel `transform-async-to-generator` plugin? If so, remove it. The babel helpers that React Native includes do not include the helper for that transform. I'm not sure how to add it without generating a new set of helpers and including them in your build.
If that plugin is not in your babel config, maybe one of the library dependencies you are using has it.

Comment: I am using "transform-decorators-legacy" - could that be linked?? Again, The app works fine on Android

Answer (score 0):

So I use expo with my project and I had this exact same issue a few days ago, was bothering the hell out of me... ultimately fixed it by importing the library - `babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator`

Here is my babelrc file for reference though: 
`

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-async-to-bluebird",
        "transform-async-to-generator",
        "transform-react-jsx-source",
        [
          "module-resolver",
          {
            "root": ["./src"]
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-async-to-bluebird",
        "transform-async-to-generator",
        "transform-remove-console",
        "transform-react-jsx-source",
        [
          "module-resolver",
          {
            "root": ["./src"]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
`
```